# How to use Flutter MVC design pattern

Tags: flutter, model-view-controller

I am designing an app with buttons and texts using MVC design pattern.

- Each button acts like a counter. User clicks on it and the face value decrements.
- There is also a "+" and "-" button that updates a text from 1 to 10 (within that range).

What I want to happen is when the +/- is clicked I want to update the numbers on the buttons. For example, let's think of it like a deck of cards, each face value has a count of 4, when I increase my deck (with the +/- buttons) I want that face value count to increase too. So, if there are 2 decks then there should be 8 cards of each face value, with 3 decks there would be 12 cards of each face value. When the button that is displaying the face value is clicked that count should decrement up until it reaches zero.

I tried doing the following in the **Model**:

```
static int get faceCard2 => _faceCard2 * _deckCount;
static int decrementFaceCard2() => _faceCard2 > 0 ? --_faceCard2 : 0;
```

which it worked but when you click the face card button it decrements by the deck count. So, for example, deck count = 2, the face count is 8 and then you click on that button and it decrements by 2 instead of 1. Which is expected...

I got the incrementing and decrementing to work but how to do multiply by deck count?

My **Model** has the following:

```
static int _faceCard2 = 4;
static int _deckCount = 1;

static int get faceCard2 => _faceCard2;
static int decrementFaceCard2() => _faceCard2 > 0 ? --_faceCard2 : 0;

// Deck Count changes the card count
static int get deckCount => _deckCount;
static int incrementDeckCount() => _deckCount++;
static int decrementDeckCount() => _deckCount > 1 ? --_deckCount : 1;
```

My **Controller** has the following:

```
static int get faceCard2 => ManualCountModel.faceCard2;
static void decrementFaceCard2() {
    ManualCountModel.decrementFaceCard2();
}

//Deck counting
  static int get deckCount => ManualCountModel.deckCount;
  static void incrementDeckCount() {
    ManualCountModel.incrementDeckCount();
  }

  static void decrementDeckCount() {
    ManualCountModel.decrementDeckCount();
  }
```

My **View** has the following:

```
elevatedButton(
   onClick: () {
       setState(
         ManualCountController.decrementFaceCard2,
       );
   },
   numText: '2',//face card 
   denumText: '${ManualCountController.faceCard2}', //face card count that changes when clicked on and when deck count changes
   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, starting to really like MVC for simple stuff. I used to leave all my calculations within my stateful widget, which I knew this wasn't proper programming. Separating you logic from your view has great benefits, such as, clean structure. Does it improve on performance? I will only know once my app is done!

For those who are still getting to know MVC pattern, here is my solution:

All calculations are done in model file.

to get the Card count when user increases the deck count (I'm only showing the 2's in the deck here):

```
static int get deckCount => _deckCount;
  static int incrementDeckCount() {
    _deckCount++;
    _faceCard2 = 4 * _deckCount;
    return _deckCount;
  }
```

so easy, so simple... felt silly asking this question but MVC was new to me...

controller (just like in my question):

```
static int get deckCount => ManualCountModel.deckCount;
  static void incrementDeckCount() {
    ManualCountModel.incrementDeckCount();
  }
```

The the view (even simpler):

```
setState(ManualCountController.incrementDeckCount);
```